# Force IPv4 in cURL in PHP application

Tags: php, curl, configuration, ip

Is there any way to force cURL to use IPv4? I'm looking for like a global setting, like `php.ini` setting or something like that.

Comment: @PeeHaa Is `curl_setopt` a global setting? I'm not familiar with the methodology of the other answers in that link. Could you explain them?

Answer (score 34):

Please try this code, with [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)
This will force the IPV4 resolving.

```
if (defined('CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE') && defined('CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4')){
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
}
```

the [defined](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) insure that the global constants available on your PHP version.

Comment: Ok for one call but it's not a global setting, I'm searching for a global setting.

Comment: @neoteknic did you find a way to do this globally?

Comment: No, you can't, but you cant, or you have to disable ipv6 on the system just add this line evrywhere or in a function : curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

Comment: For apache you can do :
Listen 0.0.0.0:80 instead of 80 (can work for modphp but modphp is obsolete), you can do the same think in php-fpm but it's only on server side, when you use curl it's a client so the "Listen on port setting" is another thing.

Comment: This fixed my issue (thanks). In my situation, the target host had made a change in its DNS reverse lookups. Whereas before it only revealed an IPv4 address, it now also offers an IPv6 address. But this broke the bind attempt to use a specific outgoing source IP address, which was IPv4. One might assume that since one is trying to bind to a local IPv4 IP address, the remote resolution would follow suit and use IPv4. But that's not how it works (at least in PHP 7.2). Bug/feature requests - https://curl.haxx.se/mail/tracker-2014-02/0025.html, https://curl.haxx.se/mail/tracker-2010-12/0008.html